# How to hide desktop.ini using attrib on cmd windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

After I run this code on cmd `attrib -h -r -s /s C:\*.*` desktop.ini appears on desktop, documents etc. how can i back it on default ? on my folder options I already click Restore Defaults but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you recursively changed the attributes of all (or at least most) files in `C:`. I doubt that there's a simple decent way to revert it. But if you only care about the `desktop.ini` on your Desktop, then you can do this:

```
cd Destkop
attrib +h +s desktop.ini
```

And maybe also this (might need Administator command prompt):

```
cd C:\Users\Public\Desktop
attrib +h +s desktop.ini
```

Or maybe this to hide again all existing desktop.ini (not tested myself, just formed according the the documentation):

```
cd C:\
attrib +h +s desktop.ini /s
```

I don't think you want `+r` to add the read-only attribute to it.

Ref.: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx